# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _ruby_run when using heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I've run into this problem after I installed the newest version of the heroku toolbelt. 
If I use the `heroku` command, I get this error:

```
$ heroku -v
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _ruby_run
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libruby.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _ruby_run
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libruby.dylib

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I'm running on OSX 10.9.1 with ruby 2.1.1p76 and Rails 4.0.3 with RVM. I've reinstalled rvm, home-brew, updated ruby from 2.0.0. And started using postgresql 9.3 for development. I use postgresql 9.3 for development.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, which prevented me from using Rails or Heroku. Changing my `PATH` did nothing.

My solution was to remove Ruby from `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/lib`. Specifically, I renamed `/usr/local/bin/ruby` to `/usr/local/bin/rubyOLD` and renamed the `/usr/local/lib/ruby` directory to `/usr/local/lib/rubyOLD`.

Since heroku was also installed in `/usr/local` and it was referring to the `/usr/local` ruby, I renamed `/usr/local/bin/heroku` to `/usr/local/bin/herokuOLD` and reinstalled via the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/).

I also reinstalled rvm for good measure (`rvm implode` completely removes rvm from your system, and the [rvm website](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) website explains how to reinstall it).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a newer ruby version in `/usr/local` and an older one in `/usr`. The shared library from the older one is being linked to the binary from the new one at runtime.

Adjust your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` so that `/usr/local/lib` is before `/usr/lib`, so the `libruby.dylib` in `/usr/local/lib` is found and preferred by the linker. Or use `install_name_tool` to modify the library path on `/usr/local/bin/ruby` directly.