# Symbol not found: _ruby_run

Tags: ruby

Running:

```
ruby -v
```

Returns this:

```
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _ruby_run
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ruby
Expected in: /usr/lib/libruby.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _ruby_run
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ruby
Expected in: /usr/lib/libruby.dylib

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I have two versions of Ruby. the system and my own. Is there a conflict?

Edit: anyone else having this issue please refer to http://www.curvve.com/blog/guides/2013/install-ruby-1-9-3-mac-osx-10-8-macports-rvm/#.U-BDrF9dVja which helped me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025160/dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-ruby-run-when-using-heroku

Comment: Thanks, Hunter. I did find that but have read that it's not good practice to modify the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH so am looking for a better alternative.

Comment: Ruby isn't normally in /usr/local/bin, especially on Mac OS so how'd it get there? Do you have RVM or rbenv installed as a multi-user or system-wide installation? If so what does `rbenv which ruby` and `rbenv versions`, or `rvm info` say? Can you run `gem env`? If so, what does it say? Append the output of those to your question.

Comment: I didn't have RVM or rbenv, but installing them helped me resolve the issue. I followed some of what was here with success: http://www.curvve.com/blog/guides/2013/install-ruby-1-9-3-mac-osx-10-8-macports-rvm/#.U-BDrF9dVja